# "QgsCoordinateTransform(): arguments did not match any overloaded call" error when transforming CRS of raster with PROJ4 string using PyQGIS

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, pyqgis, proj, typeerror

I try to reproject the CRS of a raster to another common coordinate system, using this code:

```py
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem()

crs_1 = crs.createFromProj4("+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=38.03333333333 +k=1 +x_0=2400000 +y_0=-6511057.63 +ellps=krass +towgs84=23.57,-140.95,-79.8,0,0.35,0.79,-0.22 +units=m +no_defs")
crs_2 = crs.createFromProj4("+proj=utm +zone=37 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")

QgsCoordinateTransform(crs_1, crs_2, QgsProject.instance())
```

But it gives me the following `TypeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: QgsCoordinateTransform(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: too many arguments
  overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'bool'
  overload 3: argument 1 has unexpected type 'bool'
  overload 4: argument 1 has unexpected type 'bool'
  overload 5: argument 1 has unexpected type 'bool'
```

What am I doing wrong? Using EPSG numbers works but is for me no option. I am using QGIS 3.1 on Win 10.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

[`createFromProj4()`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.html#a1edc7752a75a3b3753d6079957b61f9b) seems to return a boolean value which would explain the [`TypeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError).

Try replacing this with [`fromProj4()`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.html#afebf8e84e1ca648f50a407ce3cc7ab88):

```py
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem()

crs_1 = crs.fromProj4("+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=38.03333333333 +k=1 +x_0=2400000 +y_0=-6511057.63 +ellps=krass +towgs84=23.57,-140.95,-79.8,0,0.35,0.79,-0.22 +units=m +no_defs")
crs_2 = crs.fromProj4("+proj=utm +zone=37 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")

QgsCoordinateTransform(crs_1, crs_2, QgsProject.instance())
```